# Thresholding an RGB image

Tags: image-processing, threshold, image-enhancement, adaptive-threshold

We have an RGB image. I want to apply adaptive thresholding on it. How can we find the threshold value??? I think we can separately find the threshold value of each channel but what next is the confusion?? or if you can provide some better solution it would be appreciable. Thanks.

Comment: I think you are probably looking for *"Otsu Thresholding"*... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method

Answer (score 2):

You wrote that you want to apply thresholding so I assume that you want binarized image as output. Is there any special reason that you want perform thresholding on each channel separately? If not, try convert image to grayscale and then apply thresholding. If you want you could apply thresholding on each channel separately and then merge output binarized images from each channel into one output but I don't know why you wan to do it.

Comment: Actually I am trying to find Eucledian distance between pixels base on the condition that if distance<threshold then both pixels belong to the same region where Eucledian distance DIST = sqrt(d1^2+d2^2+d3^2) where D1 is intensity difference between two pixels in the Red channel, D2 is intensity difference between two pixels in the Green channel,D3 is intensity difference between two pixels in the Blue channel. Hope you understood the problem. Now please suggest what to do. Thanks.